# How do I create lags based on a value from n years (n lags) ago with no NA's in the resulting variables?

Tags: r

I need to create 8 lagged variables based on the "adjusted_price", and "year" variable which is grouped by "field_name".
To create the first new variable "lag1", a function needs to say; "If the year is f. ex 1989, retrieve and fill in the adjusted price for the year 1988.
For "lag2" this will need to be "If the year is 1989, retrieve and fill in the adjusted price for (1989 - 2) = 1987, and so on.
For "lag8" this will need to be "If the year is 1994, retrieve and fill in the adjusted price for (1994-8) = 1986.
The first categorical group in the data frame begins at 1971. I have included prices going back more then 8 years before 1971 so that 8 lagged terms can be created for the first year as well.
When this is done there should be no NA variables in the lags, and every cell within all the 8 lag variables should consist of (If year = X, retrieve adjusted price for (X - N amount of lags).
F. ex for lag 6 in 1970: Retrieve adjusted price for (1970-6) = 1964, which is ~ 8.7294. All data needed to solve this is in the attached data frame. I copy pasted a section of the data below which should contain everything needed to test solutions.

[Data structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCQGE.png)

VOLVE,2008,136.03085553997195
VOLVE,2009,86.63380281690141
VOLVE,2010,84.36305732484077
VOLVE,2011,91.4215283483977
VOLVE,2012,85.6058282208589
VOLVE,2013,83.4435049961568
VOLVE,2014,81.12295081967214
VOLVE,2015,52.32
VOLVE,2016,56.42118863049096
YME,1996,32.69417273526051
YME,1997,29.081806665367377
YME,1998,24.97390422117514
YME,1999,30.40355195015856
YME,2000,83.77581120943954
YME,2001,80.96026490066225
YTTERGRYTA,2009,86.63380281690141
YTTERGRYTA,2010,84.36305732484077
YTTERGRYTA,2011,91.4215283483977
YTTERGRYTA,2012,85.6058282208589
YTTERGRYTA,2013,83.4435049961568
YTTERGRYTA,2014,81.12295081967214
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1988,29.19503450853079
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1989,32.060485099801475
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1990,38.35579349756489
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1991,34.384954102073706
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1992,33.78737292725787
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1993,29.918432903977582
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1994,29.995294488177166
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1995,34.40646841606222
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1996,32.69417273526051
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1997,29.081806665367377
Ã˜ST FRIGG,1998,24.97390422117514
Ã…SGARD,1999,30.40355195015856
Ã…SGARD,2000,83.77581120943954
Ã…SGARD,2001,80.96026490066225
Ã…SGARD,2002,88.37455830388693
Ã…SGARD,2003,99.41379310344827
Ã…SGARD,2004,108.85714285714285
Ã…SGARD,2005,118.99343544857769
Ã…SGARD,2006,123.37121212121214
Ã…SGARD,2007,140.8155339805825
Ã…SGARD,2008,136.03085553997195
Ã…SGARD,2009,86.63380281690141
Ã…SGARD,2010,84.36305732484077
Ã…SGARD,2011,91.4215283483977
Ã…SGARD,2012,85.6058282208589
Ã…SGARD,2013,83.4435049961568
Ã…SGARD,2014,81.12295081967214
Ã…SGARD,2015,52.32
Ã…SGARD,2016,56.42118863049096
Ã…SGARD,2017,58.648648648648646
Ã…SGARD,2018,58.33197056418643
Ã…SGARD,2019,60.48918156161807
Ã…SGARD,2020,56.09625668449198
Ã…SGARD,2021,42.86234081261371
AASTA HANSTEEN,2018,58.33197056418643
AASTA HANSTEEN,2019,60.48918156161807
AASTA HANSTEEN,2020,56.09625668449198
AASTA HANSTEEN,2021,42.86234081261371
NA,1960,9.797557222542794
NA,1961,9.469297161020272
NA,1962,9.145992911855494
NA,1963,9.047099198427013
NA,1964,8.729418139128866
NA,1965,8.380992852547644
NA,1966,7.775871926815324
NA,1967,7.583446419815034
NA,1968,7.343205865663838
NA,1969,6.795441168601851
NA,1970,6.244838976052848

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the example data to demonstrate the essence of the approach. You can extend this with the required number of lags.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~name, ~year, ~value,
  "VOLVE", 2008, 1,
  "VOLVE", 2009, 2,
  "VOLVE", 2010, 3,
  "VOLVE", 2011, 4,
  "YME", 2008, 1,
  "YME", 2009, 2,
  "YME", 2010, 3,
  "YME", 2011, 4
) |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  mutate(lag1 = lag(value),
         lag2 = lag(value, 2)) |> 
  drop_na()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name   year value  lag1  lag2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 VOLVE  2010     3     2     1
#> 2 VOLVE  2011     4     3     2
#> 3 YME    2010     3     2     1
#> 4 YME    2011     4     3     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>